# Move figure away from the first page

Tags: floats

In my LaTeX document, I don't want any figures on the first page. Is there a way to enforce this requirement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can suppress (further) floats on the current page using `\suppressfloats`. To avoid floats on the first page, just place it directly after `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`afterpage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) to postpone certain actions by one page. Here's a small example illustrating this with a figure:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\afterpage{% Place the figure *after* this page
  \begin{figure}[t]
    \centering\rule{150pt}{100pt}
    \caption{This is a figure caption}
  \end{figure}%
}
\lipsum[1-8]% dummy text
\end{document}
```

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provides some dummy text, *Lorem Ipsum* style.

Answer (score -1):

If you include just `[t]` in the figure placement specification (that is `\begin{figure}[t]`), then the figure can go only at the top of a page.  If for some reason it can't go at the top of the first page -- perhaps because the title is there -- then that'll force it to go on the next page at least.

This answer is sufficiently simple that I'm guessing you've tried something like this and it didn't work.  Are there other complications?