# Move figure away from first page, in two-column mode

Tags: floats, ieeetran

I'm trying to suppress any floats, tables and figures, from appearing on the first page in a two-column [ieeetran](/questions/tagged/ieeetran) document:

> Furthermore, IEEE journals never place floats in the first column of
>   the first page and rarely (if ever) do they do so in the second column
>   of the first page. Middle in-text placement (“here”) is not used.

But so far I have no luck.
Actually, I haven't even been able to get the `\suppressfloats` command to work at all in this set-up, on any page.

Does `\suppressfloats` even work with [ieeetran](/questions/tagged/ieeetran)?
Does `\suppressfloats` even work with `twocloumn`?

Related question: [Move figure away from the first page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54567/move-figure-away-from-the-first-page)

*Edit*
After having done some testing with the `bare_jrnl.tex` template, I've come to some conclusions, but not nearly enough to satisfy me:

- `\suppressfloats` does seem to *work* with [ieeetran](/questions/tagged/ieeetran)
- The conditions of *work* is not clear to me, i.e. it seems to be dependent on both the amount of text, sections, subsections, placement of the command (even tough they appear on the same page), placement of float in text, etc.
- placing `\suppressfloats` just after `\begin{document}` never seems to work

Even so, I still can't get latex to move my float in my original document.
Suggestions that I could move the float, in text, away is kind of hassle if it moves to far away (like different (sub)sections in different files, etc.).

Comment: You could always just move the float creation later in the document.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `\suppressfloats` does work with `IEEEtran` and, consequently, with `twocolumn` format.

As mentioned in the link you provide, just type `\suppressfloats` at the beginning of the document, right after `\begin{document}`.

Also, as stated by John Kormylo, you can simply write your `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` at some other place in your text, making it appear in the second column of the second page.

Don't forget that `IEEE` requires you to use the `[t]` specification, so all your figures should appear on top of the columns.

Comment: I've updated the question. Can get `\suppressfloats` to work, somewhat, but not nearly as deterministic as I had hoped for.